# Why am I getting different outputs in different compilers with JavaScript dates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, date, datetime

I have created below program in which I tried to compare date and time. but it is giving different answers in different compilers.

In tutorials point compiler it is working as expected :
[tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php)

But, In repl.it compiler it is giving me wrong output : [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs)

Why this problem is happening?

```
let todayDate = () => {
    var today = new Date();
    var dateAndTime = today.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' })
    var fulldate = dateAndTime.split(",")[0].split("/")
    var dd = fulldate[0]
    var mm = fulldate[1]
    var yyyy = fulldate[2]

    return yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;
}

let currentTime = () => {
    var today = new Date();
    var dateAndTime = today.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' })
    var time = dateAndTime.split(",")[1].split(":")
    var hh = time[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
    var mm = time[1]
    var ss = time[2]

    return Date.parse(`${todayDate()} ${hh}:${mm}:${ss}`);
    
}

if (currentTime() > Date.parse(`${todayDate()} 18:00:00`) && currentTime() <  Date.parse(`${todayDate()} 22:52:58`)){
console.log('Welcome')
}
else{
  console.log('Comeback Later')
}

console.log(currentTime())
console.log(todayDate())
```

Comment: This is the correct output: `Comeback Later`
`1616434360000`
`2021/03/22`

Comment: If you want portability, use ISO date format: `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal but why it is showing different output in different compilers? You can change second time 22:52:58 to later and then check it.

Comment: @BBMevada replit.com one seems to have some problem. I don't use these compilers that is why I don't know about it!

Comment: The output of *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent, so difference between implementations should be expected. `Date.parse(\`${todayDate()} ${hh}:${mm}:${ss}\`)` produces `NaN` at Replit, so results in an invalid date, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)